# Python 2.7 and Appengine ő/ű characters shown as '?'

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm developing a website in python on google app engine with mysql. My problem if I have the characters 'ő' or 'ű' in the database, the rendering shows an error or shows the '?' instead of the 'ő' or 'ű' characters.

I've already tried to change the collation in the database to `utf-8` or `latin-1`, but the result is the same.
i've also tried to use the `unidecode()`, `.decode('latin1')`, `.decode('utf8')` and added the line to my .py `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
nothing helps. sometimes i receive an 'ascii decoding error' or 'utf8 can't decode byte' error. The best what i could achieve is the '?' sign instead of the special characters.

```
this is a sample of my code:
c.execute("""select subject from mytable""")
blogs = []
for (row) in c:
    blogs.append(dict([('azon',row[0])]))
return blogs
```

if i use use this one, then the page rendering perfectly

```
c.execute("""select subject from mytable""")
blogs = []
for (row) in c:
    blogs.append(dict([('azon','ő')]))
return blogs
```

Comment: Collation only affects sorting. You need to set the `DEFAULT CHARSET` on database and/or `CHARSET` on table level to utf8 _before_ saving data to tables. Can you post the `show create database myddb` and `show create table mytable` output?

Comment: this is the output:
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 
COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci */
CREATE TABLE `blog` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `azon` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `cim` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
   `iro` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `datum` date NOT NULL,
   `szoveg` text NOT NULL,
   `kep` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
   `asdf` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Answer (score 1):

You cant change encoding type when decoding. ie an encoded `latin-1` string doesnt magically become `utf-8` if you set `utf-8` decode type.

Make sure your mysql inputs are `utf-8` first. In the mysql connection string set it to `utf-8`. Also make sure the character set on the tables is set to utf-8 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html